# Writer from python lucene has error being defined

Tags: python, search, indexing, lucene, writer

Simply running these few commands in my python idle,

```
>>> path = os.path.abspath("paths")

>>> directory = SimpleFSDirectory(Paths.get(path)) # the index

>>> analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()

>>> writerConfig = IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)

>>> writer = IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)
```

I have this error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    writer = IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)
JavaError: <super: <class 'JavaError'>, <JavaError object>>
    Java stacktrace:
org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held by this virtual machine: /Users/serenayuan/Documents/2017/paths/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory.obtainFSLock(NativeFSLockFactory.java:127)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.FSLockFactory.obtainLock(FSLockFactory.java:41)
    at org.apache.lucene.store.BaseDirectory.obtainLock(BaseDirectory.java:45)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:791)
```

I think  that I followed the right declaration conventions for python lucene and can't understand why this error keeps appearing.